# Powershell search through folders and sub folder for files with ".rtf" extension

Tags: loops, powershell, scripting, filesystems

I am trying to get all files w/in a directory that have the extension ".rtf". I have a working script, but it takes a while, as there is a foreach loop w/in a foreach loop. Is there a faster way to handle this? The goal of the script is to get all files w/in a directory ending in .rtf and use MSWord to Open the file and save it as a ".DOC". The conversion functionality works fine. The issue is with the length of time to search through all of the folders.

```
Function Convert-Dir($path)
{
$subFolders = get-childitem $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}
if($subFolders)
{
    foreach($folder in $subFolders)
    {
        if($folder.PSisContainer)
        {
            $Files=Get-ChildItem $folder.fullname -Filter "*.rtf"
            $Word=New-Object -ComObject WORD.APPLICATION

            if($Files)
            {
                foreach ($File in $Files) 
                {
                    $Doc=$Word.Documents.Open($File.fullname)

                    $Name=($Doc.name).replace("rtf","doc")

                    if (Test-Path $Name)
                    {

                    } else 
                    {
                        # Use WORD 
                        $fullName = ($Doc.path + "\" + "Converted_" + $Name)
                        $Doc.saveas([ref] $fullName, [ref] 0)  
                        $Doc.close()
                        $fileToRemove = $File.fullName
                        Remove-Item $fileToRemove
                        $Word.Quit()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is the instantiation of $subfolders not already getting all the files though all of the directories recursively? Also, is there any reason to open word to change the document from .rtf to .doc? You could use the Rename-Item command to change the file extension.

Comment: I would try something like this to start.
get-childitem $path -Recurse | % {if($_.Name -contains '.rtf'){ Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName \somepath\whatever new name is}}

Comment: @jdwal The reason for using word to open and save is that when word does this, it actually converts the file from RTF to DOC. Changing the file extension does not actually convert the code.

Comment: @jdwal It appears that it was going through recursively without needing the extra foreach loop. Thanks for that. However, I really would rather it not modify files in the first directory. Basically, the .rtf files are all in a sub directory named according to the users initials. So there is a main directory, and then lots of sub folders with users initialls for name (BHO, NAC, etc). I only want to convert the subfolder files, not the main directory (where the script is called from). Can I check the length of the end of the path in powershell?

Comment: I haven't had time to try this,  but maybe a get-content on the .rtf files and have the out-file in the pipeline set to .doc.  You might be able to set the Encoding property to whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the performance is lost by creating a lot of word-instances by calling a word-process in each subfolder. You should should use only one instance of word all the time. Just move the line `$Word=New-Object -ComObject WORD.APPLICATION` to the top of your function and the line `$word.quit()` to the very end.